# Writing data into Snowflake table using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to read data from Excel to pandas dataframe and then write the dataframe to Snowflake table. Code as below.
Connection is established and Excel read is working fine but write to snowflake table is not working. Am getting below error . Requesting help to resolve the error

***snowflake.connector.errors.MissingDependencyError: Missing optional dependency: pandas Process finished with exit code 1***

```
import pandas as pd


from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pd_writer
url = URL(
    account = '',
    user = '',
    schema = 'TMP',
    database = 'TMP',
    warehouse= 'DATABRICKS',
    role = '',
    authenticator='externalbrowser',
)

engine = create_engine(url)
con = engine.connect()
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Final.xlsx")
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
table_name = 'test_connect'
if_exists = 'replace'

df.to_sql(name=table_name.lower(), con=con,index= False, if_exists=if_exists, method=pd_writer)
```

**Detailed Error info below**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\DataSpell2022.2\scratches\scratch.py", line 32, in <module>
        df.to_sql(name=table_name.lower(), con=con,index= False, if_exists=if_exists, method=pd_writer)
      File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2963, in to_sql
        return sql.to_sql(
      File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 697, in to_sql
        return pandas_sql.to_sql(
      File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1739, in to_sql
        total_inserted = sql_engine.insert_records(
      File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1322, in insert_records
        return table.insert(chunksize=chunksize, method=method)
      File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 950, in insert
        num_inserted = exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
      File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\snowflake\connector\pandas_tools.py", line 320, in pd_writer
        df = pandas.DataFrame(data_iter, columns=keys)
      File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\snowflake\connector\options.py", line 36, in __getattr__
        raise MissingDependencyError(self._dep_name)
snowflake.connector.errors.MissingDependencyError: Missing optional dependency: pandas
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

Importing the required packages.

```
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector as snow
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas
```

Create Connection object

```
conn = snow.connect(
user="USERNAME",
password="PASSWORD",
account="ACCOUNT",
warehouse="WAREHOUSE",
database="YOUR_DATABASE_NAME",
schema="YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME")
```

Create dataframe from source data like csv

```
source_data_df = pd.read_csv('d:/temp/CCR_PLATE_LOGIC.csv')
```

Write to the table in Snowflake.

```
write_pandas(conn, source_data_df, "YOUR_TABLE_NAME", auto_create_table=True)
```

Execute select queries using cursor if you want to validate if data inserted.  Create a cursor object.

```
cur = conn.cursor()
```

Execute a statement that will turn the warehouse off.

```
sql = "select * from YOUR_TABLE_NAME"
cur.execute(sql)
```

Close your cursor and your connection.

```
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Does it create a new table for you if it doesn't already exist? This will only append to an existing table for me, I have to first create the empty table using df.to_sql(). Is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: @EeAnnNg, I added the `auto_create_table=True` argument to the `write_pandas` function.  This will create the table if it doe not already exist.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following dependency install step has not been completed: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html#installation